# How can i get the property attributes in django model

Tags: python, django

I  am getting the fields of models like this

```
model._meta.fields
```

But i also want to get fields which declared as `@property`

How can i get those fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import inspect
inspect.getmembers(SomeClass, inspect.isdatadescriptor)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html

Comment: That shows all of them including fields . Is there any way i can separate property from them . i need them separately

Comment: Just exclude django fieds `[field for field in inspect.getmembers(SomeClass, inspect.isdatadescriptor) if ...]`

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
model.__dict__
```

or

```
dir(model)
```

?